# Restrict user accessing the application in other tab

Tags: c#, asp.net

We are developing secure web application using asp.net C#.
After User is logged in to the application,  I will copy paste the URL to other tab of the same browser. I need to restrict user accessing the application in other tab or expire his session ID and bring back to login page.

please help me in doing this.

Comment: Since that won't be possible easily, I just wonder where that restriction comes from. Isn't there a better way to catch multiple sessions server side? See this as to why per-tab-sessions are problematic: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/805895/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the solution for this.
I referred http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/MultipleTabWindows.aspx.
Its working fine.Hope it is useful to others

Comment: it's been deleted